# Using filter inside a calculated memeber

Tags: filter, mdx

I'm having some MDX issues, I want to calculate how many products I have per type per version, this would be my output.

ProductID | QtyProductAVersionA | QtyProductAVersionB | QtyProductBVersionA | QtyProductBVersionB |

I have this MDX so far

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ProductAVersionA]
AS  SUM([DimProduct].[ProductName].&[ProductA],[Measures].[ProductQty])
SELECT NON EMPTY (
        [Measures].[ProductAVersionA]) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [DimOrg].[ProductID].[ProductID].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Sales]
WHERE([DimCustomers].[Customer Area].&[United States])
```

But this returns the total of product A, I want only the product A filtered by version A. I can't use it in the **WHERE** clause since not all my products have the same versions.
Is there any way I can achieve this with a Filter expression inside the calculated memeber? I tried to used but I kept getting an error.

FYI product version is in another dimension **[DimVersion]**

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try filtering the ProductAVersionA calculated member by the DimVersion 'A' member as follows:

```
member [Measures].[ProductAVersionA] as
    sum(([DimProduct].[ProductName].&[ProductA], [DimVersion].[VersionName].&[VersionA]), [Measures].[ProductQty])
```

Comment: Well that was easy :) man I tried the same approach only that used {} instead of ().
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Ah yes, the classic set vs tuple problem. Have a read of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216769%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to understand the difference.